# C# random letter generator with specified ratio of consonants:vowels

Tags: c#, string, random, console

I need to create code to scatter 50 random letters into the console (It's a "Snake" game); that part, I didn't have a problem with. I used this code to generate the letters (the "scatter them around the console" part I'm handling once I know how to fix the problem)

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.Next(0, 26);
        char letter = (char)('a' + number);
```

It generates random letters just fine, but the instructions for the problem specify ***the ratio of consonants to vowels must be 4:1***, and I have no idea how to make that part happen.

Comment: Without doing anything special, the ratio will be 4.2:1 since there are 21 consonants and 5 vowels.

Comment: @SteveWellens Doesn't your technique suffer from a problem that some consonants will be selected more than others? The bag of 40 consonants will have 2 copies of 19 consonants, and only 1 of the other 2.

Comment: @Barmar The [letter Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y) can represent a vowel or a consonant. So if it's removed from the possible letter choices because of its ambiguity, then the ratio will be 4:1 -- 20 consonants and 5 vowels. #Voila!

Comment: @Barmar - The bag of 40 consonants may have 2 copies of 19 consonants and only 1 of the other 2.  It may also have the letter k 4 times.  It is supposed to be random which means a possible uneven distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Create a pair of static strings:

```
  String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

  String vowels = "AEIOU";
```

Generate a random number between 1..5 (or 0..4). If the number is 1 (0), pick a random character from the vowels list. Otherwise pick a random character from the consonants list.

Alternately, if you need *exactly* the ratio of 4:1, use a for-loop in place of the first random number generator, to wit:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
{
    if ( i % 5 == 0 )
    // select a vowel at random
    else
    // select a consonant at random
}
```

EDIT: Complete solution. I'm writing my fifty characters to an array then printing them to the console. You can pass `theChar` to your output method.

```
    public void RandomChars()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
        String vowels = "AEIOU";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            char theChar;

            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                theChar = vowels[random.Next(vowels.Length)];
            }
            else
            {
                theChar = consonants[random.Next(consonants.Length)];
            }

            result.Append(theChar);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: And just to make sure I understand, for the "select a vowel/consonant", it'd look something like:

`if (i % 5 == 0)
{
number = rand.Next(0,20);
letter = (char)('b' + number)
}
else
{
number = rand.Next(0,4);
letter = (char)('a' + number)
}`

Am I understanding right?